# customize category page in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I am  a newbie in magento. Please let me know how can I edit my category page.
If I want to add some html code to a particular category then from which file should I for in magento root folder.

Please help.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new perhaps you should start with the [designer's guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide) and [theming wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/All%20Categories?idx=4_-_themes_and_template_customization:0_-_theming_in_magento).

The difficulty with theming is no one file is responsible, about the best trick you can learn is using [template hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/).

Comment: actually i wanted to know where is the html file responsible for showing the category page located in magento root folder.

Comment: Use [template hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/) to find out which file is being used for your theme.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to add to the category and not modify the existing output, then one option is to create a Static Block with whatever html that you want, and then edit your category and choose that block in the "Display Settings" tab.